# susy как сместить колонку

Tags: javascript, css, css3

susy как сместить колонку ? Например наша сетка состоит из 12 колонок,  первый блок состоит из 6 колонок, и его нужно расположить начиная с 3-й колонки.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться `shorthand` - [span](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/shorthand/#span). 
Так же возможно вам поможет [Данная статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/241844/)

```
// span: 3;
// location: 4;
// layout: (columns: 12, gutters: .25, math: fluid)
$span: 3 at 4 of 12 .25 fluid;
```